# barra de progreso al cargar pagina en un web view android

Tags: android

> Buenas tardes, resulta que tengo una webview an android me funciona perfecto al iniciar la petición pero al momento de cargar otra pagina no muestra el progreso.
>   este es el código que funciona bien pero sola al iniciar la carga de la pagina principal.

```
    package com.barest.barest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar bar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        bar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebclient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://miweb/index.html");

    }

    public class myWebclient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan, debes hacer visible nuevamente el Progressbar mediante : bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: perfecto te lo agradezco

Comment: Excelente @juanperez un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambias la visibilidad de tu `ProgressBar` al terminar de cargar la página :

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Pero no vuelves a cambiar su visibilidad, usa el método `onPageStarted()` para volver a mostrarlo mediante `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`:

```
@Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //* muestra ProgressBar
    }
```